# to find a smallest positive integer of this type

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find a smallest integer divisible by $2,3$ and also square and fifth power.

Let $n $ be such. In prime factorization of $n$, we will have 2 and 3 as prime factors

$n = 2 . 3  . p_1 . . . $

Since n is square , so we will have even power in prime factorization

$n = 2^{t_1} . 3 ^{t_2} .. p_1^{t_3} .. .$, where $t_i$ are all even.

Also,  $n = r^5$ , so $t_i$ is multiple of $10$

Can we say that $2^{10} 3^{10}$ is smallest such number ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct

Comment: There is a rather trivial solution to this: $n=0$

Comment: Presumably you meant to say "integer $>0$".  Otherwise, there's $-6^{10n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @lulu yes that...